# Make blogger load faster

Tags: blog, page-speed, blogger

I use Blogger as a platform for an electronic music blog. Because of the thematics of the blog I embed many iframes (Youtube & Soundcloud). Of course this makes the articles load slowly. Almost every article on this blog consists of some text and many iframes below. What should I do in this particular case in order to make the pages load faster. Is there any available solution or I should use some jQuery like lazy load to load iframes once the scroller reaches them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution: use fewer iFrames.

The more complicated solution: Use your web server to actually proxy the content using a `Reverse Proxy` of where the iFrames point to, then cache the content on YOUR server, serve as if it is your own content.

Failing that, it entirely depends on your visitors' internet connections, computers, etc. If one of the framed sites loads fast for you, it may not load fast for your visitors. The browser has to make separate requests for every image and resource on each of the separate iFramed sites, then load them at the same time or slightly after your own HTML content.